# MongoDB installation failing

Tags: 12.04, upstart, mongodb

I am following the simple steps to install mongoDB:

First:

```
apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv 7F0CEB10
```

Worked Good

Second:

```
echo "deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen" | tee -a /etc/apt/sources.list.d/10gen.list
deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen
```

Done

Third:

```
apt-get -y update
```

Done

Fourth:

```
apt-get install mongodb-10gen
```

But this step failed with following message:

```
Failed to fetch http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/10gen/binary-amd64/mongodb-10gen_2.4.9_amd64.deb  Size mismatch
```

I am not able to get what am I doing wrong as I have been following these steps for a while and they were successful.

Answer (score 2):

Adding Repository

```
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver hkp://keyserver.ubuntu.com:80 --recv 7F0CEB10

echo 'deb http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart dist 10gen' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/mongodb.list
```

Install MongoDB

```
sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get install mongodb-org
```

or

```
sudo apt-get install mongodb-org=2.6.0 mongodb-org-server=2.6.0 mongodb-org-shell=2.6.0 mongodb-org-mongos=2.6.0 mongodb-org-tools=2.6.0
```

Start/Stop MongoDB Service

```
sudo service mongod start

sudo service mongod stop
```

Verify MongoDB Installation

```
mongo --version
```

Answer (score 0):

I just tested from here and succeeded in installing the 2.4.9 package.  Is it possible something on your network is blocking/intercepting/redirecting some URLs?  That has been the cause of such size mismatches that I have seen previously.

Try fetching the package itself and then installing with dpkg, something like this:

```
wget http://downloads-distro.mongodb.org/repo/ubuntu-upstart/dists/dist/10gen/binary-amd64/mongodb-10gen_2.4.9_amd64.deb
sudo dpkg -i mongodb-10gen_2.4.9_amd64.deb
```

For reference, here's the size of my file:

```
> ls -al mongodb-10gen_2.4.9_amd64.deb 
> -rw-r--r-- 1 adam adam 88012070 Jan 29 17:14 mongodb-10gen_2.4.9_amd64.deb
```

And here's an md5 for comparison:

```
> md5sum mongodb-10gen_2.4.9_amd64.deb
> d13eab1da5ffa2a36a30ea4a98ef9514  mongodb-10gen_2.4.9_amd64.deb
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, but i have installed it using a .deb file. :)